# Wrapper for commonly used database classes

Tags: c#, object-oriented, sql

The main idea behind this class is to create a wrapper for commonly used Database classes. I'm new to SOLID principles and I'm trying to implement them in this library. Does this code adhere to SOLID principles?

```
//This is the opens the SQL Connection and is placed in DbConnectionSetup.cs   

 public interface IConnectionProvider
{
    SqlConnection OConnection(string ConnectionString);
}

public abstract class DatabaseAttributes
{
    private string _connectionString = null;

    private string _command = null;

    public virtual string ValidateConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return this._connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _connectionString = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No Connection String property detected.");
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual string ValidateSqlCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this._command;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _command = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No Command String detected.");
            }
        }
    }
}

[Description("This opens the Sql Connection")]
public class SqlOpenConnection : DatabaseAttributes, IConnectionProvider
{
    public SqlConnection OConnection(string ConnectionString)
    {
        ValidateConnectionString = ConnectionString;

        var _dbConConnection = new SqlConnection(ValidateConnectionString);

        try
        {
            if (_dbConConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _dbConConnection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("SqlException thrown", ex);
        }

        return _dbConConnection;
    }
}

/* I have a different class called SqlOps.cs which has the following code:*/

public interface ICommandWithParams
{
    int ExecuteCommandWithParams(string ConnectionString, string Command, Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> Params);
}

//have one function to Insert,Update and delete

public class ExecuteComplexCud : DatabaseAttributes, ICommandWithParams
{
    public int ExecuteCommandWithParams(string ConnectionString, string Command, Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> Params)
    {
        int rc;
        IConnectionProvider _dbCon = new SqlOpenConnection();//Get OConnection from DbConnectionSetup.cs

        ValidateSqlCommand = Command;//Check for Empty Command
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand _sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(ValidateSqlCommand, _dbCon.OConnection(ConnectionString)))
            {
                _sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                foreach (var keyValuePair in Params)
                {
                    _sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(keyValuePair.Value);
                }
                rc = _sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close the connection and dispose the object
            IConnectionProvider _dbCloseCon = new SqlCloseConnection();
            _dbCloseCon.OConnection(ConnectionString);
        }

        return rc;
    }
}
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, it's unclear to me what exactly you want to achieve with this code. Database access, yes, but what benefits should your code provide? Why don't you want to use `SqlConnection` (or `IDbConnection`) and its associated classes directly?

Without knowing what sort of abstraction level you want to provide (and why), I think adherence to SOLID principles is a moot point. But here's what I think:

**Overall design**

It looks like you're taking the 'S' in SOLID a bit too far. Writing a separate class for each possible operation *can* be useful in certain situations, but here it only seems to complicate things. It also looks like your code doesn't actually work correctly: the `SqlConnection` returned by `SqlOpenConnection.OConnection` is never passed to that `SqlCloseConnection` instance, so how can it close that connection? And why would you need to create a new object to close an existing connection anyway? That's not intuitive.

Note that using a `SqlConnection` directly allows you to use a `using` statement, which would result in cleaner (and correct) code. I don't see any added value in those `SqlOpenConnection` and `SqlCloseConnection` classes. A single `Database` class that offers various methods for storing and retrieving data would be less complicated, and still serve a single purpose (database access).

I don't see any code that's using your interfaces (except inside `ExecuteComplexCud.ExecuteCommandWithParams`, but that seems to be an implementation detail of your library), so it's hard to tell how useful those interfaces really are - and thus how well you're taking the 'I' in SOLID into account.

**Exception handling**

You don't need to catch an exception if you're just going to throw it.

The type of an exception is a useful piece of information. `SqlException` indicates that the problem is related to database access. By wrapping that in a generic `Exception`, calling code is no longer able to distinguish database related exceptions from other exceptions. Wrapping can be useful, for example if you want to hide implementation details. In that case, your library may want to provide its own exception type, such as `DatabaseException`. Also think about what information the caller wants or needs in order to handle such exceptions.

**Other notes**

Use methods instead of properties to validate something. Properties are used to store or retrieve information. Using them otherwise will make your code harder to understand and maintain.

Another reason to remove the `ValidateConnectionString` and `ValidateSqlCommand` properties is that there doesn't seem to be any reason to store that information - and certainly not in multiple locations (`SqlOpenConnection`, `SqlCloseConnection`, `ExecuteComplexCud`).

Note that validation implies that the syntax or structure of the connection or command string will be checked. A simple null-or-empty check does not live up to that expectation. Either perform a full validation, or just remove those validation methods and use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead. And since the connection and command strings are passed as arguments, it's better to throw an `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentNullException` if they're invalid.

`OConnection` is not a descriptive name. I assume it's short for `OpenConnection`? If so, `SqlCloseConnection.OpenConnection` doesn't make any sense.

You may also want to add documentation. Describe the purpose of each interface and method, what input they consider invalid (and how they will react to that), what edge cases need to be taken into account and which exceptions they can throw.

Regarding `'//have one function to Insert,Update and delete'`, do those methods have their own class or interface, or are they part of one of the interfaces you have shown here?

**Conclusion**

Without knowing the reasoning behind your design decisions, I'd say this code is overly complicated. It's making writing a correct program harder instead of easier. As for SOLID principles, I think there's too little context shown here to determine how well this code is adhering to them.

I hope you found this helpful. Feel free to add more context or explanation to your post if you want to receive more accurate feedback.

Comment: Great points in your "other notes" Consider this comment an additional +1

Answer (score 5):

#### Typical Conventions

Parameters to methods and local variables have a lower case first letter. Methods normally have all words spelled out completly. (specially calling out `IConnectionProvider`).

### S - Single Responsibility Principle

With the very focused view point of the definition your classes adhear to the principle. Is it executed properly? No. `DatabaseAttributes` for instance. The name suggests it is a collection of attributes pertaining to a database. I suppose things like size, file, database type, version would match that type of qualification. Instead you have two properties that are ***validating*** the connection string and command string. Having a single validation class could arguably violate SRP, but maybe with some rewording and architecting maybe it coudl change to `NotNullOrEmpty` and could be used kind of like `NotNullOrEmpty.Validate(connectionString);` On the point of that class I think reversing your test logic woudl be in order. example:

```
set
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        throw new Exception("No Connection String property detected.");
    }
    _connectionString = value;
}
```

### L - Liskov substitution principle

Possible that I don't understand this one as well as I should, but you have 1 cited class and 1 mentioned class that implement `IConnectionProvider`. Naming aside, just by guessing what `SqlOpenConnection` and `SqlCloseConnection` does they are not able to be substituted one for the other. Now if you had an interface `IOpenConnectionToDatabase` and `ICloseConnectionToDatabase` and make each child class of those be able to work with any different type of provider then you'd have it.

### D -  Dependency Inversion principle

Entities must depend on abstractions not on concretions. It states that the high level module must not depend on the low level module, but they should depend on abstractions. You have code that relies on `SqlConnection`, `SqlParameters`, and all things Microsoft Sql Server. What if you wanted to switch to `MySql`, or `Postrges`, or `NoSql`.. etc etc. You wouldn't be able to because you are not relying on the abstraction. (hint, look at the System.Data.Common namespace..specifically `System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("provider name here")` )